# Transfer function for resistor and capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function

For the given circuit
[image]

**how am i going to find the transfer function H(s) between A and
B can be obtained the following equation i.e**
[image]

[image: the fractional order equation comparable to H(s)]

Comment: Your question (If it stands as an actual question) doesn’t make sense.

Comment: The only unknown in your equation is `s`, are you asking how to find that value?

Comment: A transfer function (TF) links a response to a stimulus. What TF do you want for this 3rd-order circuit? In other words, what is \$H\$ in your expression?

Comment: @RonBeyer I wanted to know that how they form the equation of H(s) from the circuit diagram?

Comment: @VerbalKint i m sorry but i m new to these things . i have updated the question with the equation which is comparable to the H(s)

Comment: @Andyaka i wanted to reproduce the research paper in which they have the equation of fractional as given above . After this they have give circuit having points A and B and its says that for " the transfer function H(s) between A and
B can be obtained as follows: " i.e the eqaution with resistors and capacitors. Now i wannna know how they did it

Comment: If it's a transfer function you're looking for then you need to specify an input signal and an output signal. At the moment, with no ground shown, it's anybody's guess where these signals may. Or are you just looking for the Laplace transform expression for the impedance between A and B? Whichever of these it may be, I don't know where \$\frac{1}{s^{0.9}}\$ comes from or what it means.

Comment: I think it is the impedance between nodes A and B: for \$s=0\$ in your expression, the equation simplifies to \$Z_{AB}=R_1+R_2+R_3\$. For a third-order network like this, you should apply the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs.

Comment: @Chu yes only the laplace transformation between A and B. The 1/s comes from Linear transfer function approximations of fractional integrator

Comment: @VerbalKint any book or link if u have? that would be amazing..

Comment: The \$ \dfrac{1}{s^{0.9}}\$ is an approximation of the transfer function, as @VerbalKint answered. They probably used some fitting/optimization to get the values for the resistor and capacitors such that the TF equals that fractional \$s\$

Comment: @Chu there is a whole new area on fractional calculus and they probably want to implement a fractional derivative or something, I assume they devised a circuit that approximates that fractional \$s^{0.9}\$ for some values of \$s\$, and that the TF is for the impedance of the circuit.

Comment: @jDAQ Thank you, that's opened a window.

Answer (score 1):

The transfer function describing the impedance "seen" between terminals A and B can be determined following two or more methods: brute-force algebra or fast analytical circuits techniques also called [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371). The first approach will lead to many lines of algebra and perhaps total paralysis after a few attempts to simplify the expression:

\$Z_{AB}(s)=(((\frac{1}{sC_1}||R_1)+R_2)||(\frac{1}{sC_2})+R_3)||\frac{1}{sC_3}\$

The FACTs, on the other hand, will let you determine the transfer function by inspecting small sketches, without writing a single line of algebra. Furthermore, the result will already be expressed in the so-called *low-entropy* form.

First, we determine the resistance "seen" from AB when \$s=0\$: all caps are open, what is the resistance \$R_0\$? Then, set the excitation to 0 A (open-circuit the current source) and determine the resistance "seen" across each capacitor's connecting terminals. At some point, you set one of the capacitor in its high-frequency state (a short circuit) and determine the resistance seen from the other caps. It sounds complicated but it's not, see the below sketch for all cases:

[image]

Then, to determine the zeroes, you have to null the response meaning the voltage \$V_T\$ is 0 V. A current source with 0 V across its terminals is replaced by a short circuit (this is a so-called degenerate case) and you repeat the exercise above alternatively looking into each cap. terminals:

[image]

When you have all the above time constants, you combine them together in a Mathcad sheet or equivalent to form the impedance starting with a leading term, \$R_0\$ followed by a numerator and a denominator:

[image]

You can then rework the expression and show a dominant low-frequency pole followed by a second-order system featuring a low quality factor. If you test your expression versus the one I found by subtracting their respective magnitude and phase, you can see they are rigorously equivalent.

[image]

In my expression, you immediately see the leading value for \$s=0\$ and the arrangement of a pole and a second-order polynomial. I could rework the numerator but it's getting late. If there is a deviation between your formula and mine, I just have to identify which of the small sketches is guilty and I can individually fix it. I can also use SPICE to verify if my inspections are correct via a dc point calculation. Impossible to do with the brute-force approach: you swear and restart from scratch :-) You now have everything to rework your expression. Good luck!

Comment: That is a really good answer, but could you improve the 3rd and 4th figures? They are really hard to read.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have many options to do this. When you click on the picture and display it, is it still hard to read? It is not that bad on my screen.

Comment: Clicking on it improves fig3, but not much for 4, well thanks anyway, really informative answer.

Comment: @VerbalKint I dont know what to say but it is very difficult, but ill try. fig 3 is impossible to read ..

Comment: @zweo download the images. It's easier to look at (although not perfect).